# VBA-Detecting Paste Action in other Programs

Tags: vba, excel

My goal: To gave Microsoft Excel notice that I have pasted the contents of my clipboard in any other window, so that it then selects the next item in the row and copies it.

For example, in a spreadsheet whose first row looks like this:

A,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

If I were to copy A, open up notepad (or any other program), and paste, excel would then proceed to copy b. If I paste again into notepad, it would select and copy C, functionally allowing me to copy just A, and then be able to go into another program and hit ctrl-v 7 times and get A thru H in my output.

It is an odd question, and in a world of easy automation, seems highly inefficient. I am however, bound by legal contract to not utilize certain kinds of automation. This however, would fall within what I am legally permitted to do, however.

Does anyone have any thoughts? I have not been able to find any documentation on this kind of issue.

Comment: Pretty sure the only way to do this would be to subclass the other program and intercept `WM_PASTE` messages.

Comment: How about driving it from the destination application? Have the destination application copy the data from the source into the destination? Or use an intermediary?

Comment: @ThunderFrame - You mean post the `WM_PASTE` instead of waiting for the user to paste manually?

Comment: Seems like an odd legal contract.

Comment: It's definitely an odd rule, but basically, we'32 touching a database that we aren't allowed to have any kind of automation attached to it. It's accessed via browser. We're not even permitted to do things like having a macro move a cursor to the appropriate place so a user can paste it, as that's too automated. Basically anything we can do has to be done entirely with regard to the way the user gets data to input. How it is entered into the system is locked. Like I said, we had to fight to be allowed to even copy/paste.

Comment: It's a little unclear. Is the data you want to copy in Excel? And you want to paste to a .Txt file? And you *can use VBA*? Or is the data in Program Z, but you want to have Excel VBA (which is allowed legally by your contract) notice you copied from Program Z and pasted to Program Y?  I know how protective people can be with their data but have y'all explained the huge constraint this is on getting the job done? Perhaps they're not too tech savvy and by explaining that you'll have to spend many many additional man hours ( "cost a lot more per hour") that if they can loosen it, everyone wins?

Comment: Because `Ctrl-C` is somehow different than `Range.Copy`? Sounds like they need a reality check.

Comment: Excel doesn't copy anything to the clipboard except a flag saying it could (until it exits, so the data exists and can be pasted without Excel). This is to save memory. Therefore Excel will be notified if any pastes occur, as it has to provide the data. From help *The system sends the clipboard owner a WM_RENDERFORMAT message when a request is received for a specific format that has not been rendered*. So subclass Excel's window and handle that message.

Comment: Hello! Thank you, Noodles! I will give this a try!

Comment: @Brucewayne: oh yes. We just happen to be dealing with the government here, with a running theme of "meet the metric, under these constraints, or don't get paid."

Comment: I work for a global bank. They are not government, and we have the same type of restrictions. Try below, should cut out the screen swapping and using cut and paste. I didn't take into account whether you want a new line or not. I'm sure you can work it out if you do want a new line each time you want to paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the cells and write straight into a text file. Variable "x" moves across the columns. Variable "n" is the number of times it prints it before moving to the next column.

```
Sub textfile()

Dim PrintVal As String
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Filename As Object

Set Filename = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\print.txt", True, True)


For x = 0 To 7

PrintVal = Cells(1, 1 + x).Value

For n = 1 To 7
Filename.write PrintVal
Next n

Next x

Filename.Close

End Sub
```